# Future data is not yet available for table error when running Create or replace table CLONE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Recently, in the last few days, we're having lot's of errors about "Future data is not yet available for table " when running a

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <tbl name> CLONE <db>.<schema>.tmp_<tbl name> COPY GRANTS
```

query. This was happening out-of-the-blue and there's no any indication about this specific error in the documentation or in the knowledge base.

What's the error in here? To what is it referring to and how can we avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have similar problem, have you made bug report

Answer (score 0):

The tables you want to clone seem to be marked as dropped. Probably undropping your table is helping: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/undrop-table.html

Comment: Hi @Marcel.
Thanks. However, the source table was just created in SF, few seconds before, using `CREATE TABLE <tbl> as SELECT` clause. Is it can be a delay on SF side that marks the table to be not-existed yet or not created, even though the create clause succeeded?
Moreover, when the table is marked as dropped - the error message is:

```
SQL compilation error: Object <tbl> does not exist or not authorized.

```

Comment: Can you share your full script (Creating, Cloning, ...) please?

Comment: Yes - 

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE INTERNAL.AUTOMATION.tmp_properties_9b80
                                    COPY GRANTS 
                                    AS
                                    select .... from ...;
         
commit;`


And then In a new session - 

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  INTERNAL.AUTOMATION.tmp_properties CLONE INTERNAL.AUTOMATION.tmp_properties_9b80 COPY GRANTS;
` 
<- Fails here.

Returned:
`000708 (02000): Future data is not yet available for table tmp_properties_9b80.`

Comment: I have seen Future error before , that was when i tried to clone data from future (thanks to timezones) but in my error which is produced just by using war clone command without AT it should not try that. my best guess is that snowflake warehouses run at different times and inner implementation gets confused

Comment: Just wanted to update that this was a internal error in SF side which raised as the error in the question,

Answer (score 0):

It seems you hit a transient issue which affected some clone operations. The issue is fixed already. You should not see this error anymore.

If you still see it, please contact he Snowflake Support.